# Have created a 3D array of chess boards, how can I add more boards to this?

Tags: python, numpy

```
neighboringStates = np.array([
  
  [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

  [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
  
])
```

Wondering how I can add another 8x8 of zeros and ones and add it to this already existing 3D array. Thanks!

Comment: import numpy as np

# Define the new 8x8 array of zeros and ones
new_array = np.array([
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
])

# Use np.concatenate() to add the new array to the existing 3D array
neighboringStates = np.concatenate((neighboringStates, np.array([new_array])))

# Print the updated 3D array
print(neighboringStates)

Comment: you cannot change the size of a `numpy.ndarray` object. You can create a new one though, in this case, probably using `numpy.concatenate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.concatenate()` to add a new array to the existing 3D array

Example Code:

```
 import numpy as np

neighboringStates = np.array([  
   [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

  [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
])

new_array = np.array([
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
])

neighboringStates = np.concatenate((neighboringStates, np.array([new_array])))
```

Comment: Great! Let me know if this solution works out for you.

Comment: Perfect, if you could mark your question as answered so people know you already got help then it would be appreciated.